# How can I keep a python object in RAM, without using multiple processes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, pthreads, ram

I am using an external program I have no control over, which at some point calls a subprocess I can specify, passes some arguments and checks its exit status once it is done.

I want the subprocess this program calls to be a python 3 script that performs some calculations
using an object that is VERY expensive to construct and VERY large. Because the object's construction is very expensive I don't want to construct it everytime this external program calls the script, and because it takes quite a bit of space it is slow to pickle it to disk and load it every time.

My current solution to this is to have two processes, one of which constructs the object and performs the calculations if requested, and another process which is called by the external program and whose only real objective is to communicate with the first process through a socket and ask for it to perform its tasks.

The code looks roughly like this for the first process:

```
# process1.py, performs calculations
import socket
import pickle

def do_expensive_calculations(large_object, data):
   # some expensive calculations
   return value

class LargeAndSlow:
    def __init__(self):
        # some code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind('ADDRESS')
    s.listen(1)
    
    large_object = LargeAndSlow()

    while True: 
        (conn, address) = s.accept()
        data = pickle.loads(conn.recv(4096))
        value = do_expensive_calculations(large_object, data)
        conn.send(pickle.dumps(value))
```

and like this for the second one (the one the external program calls):

```
# process2.py
import sys
import socket
import pickle

def value_is_correct(value):
    # check if value is correct
    return is_correct

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect('ADDRESS')
    s.send(pickle.dumps(sys.argv))
    
    value = pickle.loads(s.recv(4096))
    if value_is_correct(value):
        s.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    else:
        s.close()
        sys.exit(1)
```

This solution, however, is actually SLOWER than just constructing the object every time, and I suspect this is due to the overhead of having multiple python processes running simultaneously and communicating via UNIX sockets (however, I could be wrong, maybe I just coded this in a very inefficient way).

Is there a faster, more efficient solution to this problem?

Comment: If the object is serializable, you can dump it to a file and `mmap()` it in the process the external program invokes. That way, you have less IPC. If the file is frequently accessed and there is memory to spare, a decent OS will keep the file in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a ram disk partition and mount it as a regular filesystem. On Unix systems you can use [`tmpfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs) for the purpose.

From the program point of view, your file will look like a regular file. Nevertheless, the OS will store it in memory.

Keep in mind that the speed improvement you might (or might not) notice will depends on many factors. I/O could be one of them and there `tmpfs` will help. Nevertheless, the bottleneck might be something else such as the pickling/unpickling process.

Comment: This is a very good idea, I gave it a try and it looks like in this case the unpickling process is the bottleneck unfortunately, but this can for sure work in some cases. I may accept this as an answer if no one suggests anything else that specifically works for me.

Comment: To speed up the pickling/unpickling process you may use the [highest protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL). Make sure the same version of Python is used across all processes though.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.8, Python's multiprocessing library has already supported the `SharedMemory` class. It can let multiple processes to directly access the same memory area. Thus there will be no overhead to move the large objects around different processes. You can refer to [Python's document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) for more details.

If you are not using Python 3.8, there is a Python package [SharedArray](https://pypi.org/project/SharedArray/) which has similar functionality.

Comment: This is a very good idea, but from what I saw in the documentation you posted SharedMemory doesn't really provide a way for storage of arbitrary objects. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can uses pickle to have the job done. `pickle.dumps` will give you a byte object so you can just write into the `SharedMemory` buffer. Then `pickle.loads` will resume the object from the byte string. If you want to save memory, compress it and use the highest pickle protocol. You can use `compress_pickle` package to do the compression job. In this way, you can have a "storage" process running in the background and have another script to fetch the shared memory from the "storage" process.